# Verb 'Help' with what 'infinitive'?

Tags: word-usage

Which of the following sentences is *or* are correct:

1. Doing sports **helps keeping** fit.
2. Doing sports **helps keep** fit.
3. Doing sports **helps to keep** fit.

Thank you.

Comment: **...helps you [to] keep fit** would be the usual way to say it.